# Git clone does not work in using Cygwin to run git

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I was able to 'git clone a repository using `git clone` in my MS Terminal (the one start by using `cmd`).

```
git clone git+ssh://michael@103.116.29.18/~/Src/Test
```

But when I do the SAME command under Cygwin, it just hangs.
I have checked they are using the same instance of Git so my question is why it does not work under Cygwin?

Comment: Just guessing here, but it probably has to do with the ssh key. Make sure that a) you have a public key in your $CYGHOME/.ssh and b) that your server is aware of that key.

Comment: I open cygwin terminal and then cd to '~' I assume it is the $CYGHOME. There is a '.ssh' directory, but it is empty. how can I create a public key to access my other machine?

Comment: @michael: See section "Tunneling" on [this page](http://www.tigris.org/nonav/scdocs/ddSSHGuideCygwin.html#tunneling).

Comment: `ssh-keygen -t rsa` OR `ssh-keygen -t dsa`

Comment: I did this, but it just hangs as well $ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Programs/cygwin/home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa): id_rsa

Comment: Try using `ssh://` instead of `git+ssh://`. Also try `git clone -vv ssh://michael@103.116.29.18/~/Src/Test` if the former doesn't work, and see if the verbose output shows any clues.

Comment: @swasheck : I guess you mean `$HOME`, not `$CYGHOME`?

Comment: Maybe stupid question:  Can you ping the host you are trying to connect to? Maybe it's simply a network problem. Are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is when you don't install Git on Cygwin and Cygwin uses your official installation of Git on your Windows machine. So, when you try any action that requires connection to an external repository (push, pull, clone) it just hangs. In my case I already had installed Git on my machine, so when I checked on Cygwin if Git was present using 'git --version' Git respond.

You need to run Cygwin installer again and install Git package.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This has always worked well for me

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C svnpenn@gmail.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/Steven/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/home/Steven/.ssh'.

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:

Your identification has been saved in /home/Steven/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/Steven/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
e2:83:fc:1c:62:b6:33:ec:69:80:86:f9:1a:5d:ab:8d svnpenn@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|.o  . . S        |
|+o.o + .         |
|o..oB +          |
| ..*=* o         |
|..Eo=oo          |
+-----------------+
```

[**ref**](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git)

Answer (score 0):

I created a user environment variable CYGHOME that points to my %USERPROFILE%, and I immediately stopped having this problem. It didn't make a new SSH key or anything. Not like it should, either, since clone happens over HTTPS these days.

Comment: YES, thanks. I added also the varivale CYGHOME and it works fine now. I added also CYGWIN=tty ntsec just for ssh

Comment: Where was this variable made? In the `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

I copied .ssh/ corresponding to git into that corresponding to cygwin and that allowed me to use git commands in cygwin